# Need algorithm for Sequence calculation

Tags: java, data-structures, analytical

I am trying to find the solution for a problem where i have something like

1. A > B
2. B > C
3. B > D
4. C > D

And I should get the answer as A > B > C > D.

Conditions for this problem

1. The output will involve all the elements.
2. The problem will not have any bogus inputs.
   for example, (A>B) (C>D) is a bogus input, since we cannot determine the output.
3. The inputs can be of any size but never bogus and there will always be a solution to the problem.

I need to find a solution for this optimally using Java Collections. Any tips/hints are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called a Topological Sort.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Given that, you should be able to complete your homework on your own.

Comment: Great response to a homework question! Very specific, yet leaving much to be figured-out to the student!

Comment: Offhand, I seem to recall that top. sort will return a result even if there are several possible answers.  I think the Qn wants to ensure the answer is unique (i.e., fail if it is not).

Comment: Thank you very much for the heads up! I will take on from here

Comment: @Charles Stewart: "ensure the answer is unique"?  Where did you read that?

Comment: @S.Lott: it is not clearly asserted as a requirement, but talk of "bogus problems", which are said to be problems without unique solns, suggested that to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting you recently covered graphs in this class...
How do you think a graph could be applied here ?
Can you think of a structure which one would build on the basis of the problem inputs  (A>B>, A>D, C>A etc.)?  Maybe some kind of directed graph...

Once the problem is expressed in such a graph, the solution would involve navigating this graph...

Answer (score 0):

You start putting them in a `List`. The list will be sorted, so for the `n`th pair `(a, b)`, you look up `a`, using a binary search. If it exists already skip, if not you insert in at proper point. Since `a > b`, you do that again with `b` in the remaining part of the List. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Map of the inputs and a recursive method that adds it's answer to a returned List (or just prints each node as it descends the tree.)  If you are returning the answer then **pre**-pending to the returned list will prevent the answer from being reversed D->C->B->A when complete (or you can just .reverse() the list at the end.)  Don't forget to test for a break condition when recursing. (hint: key not found)